# Can I answer the same question multiple time?

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

**If there are many aspects to a question and that an answer should be split in many parts, does it makes sense to provide multiple answers?**

I know that some would like to flag the question as "too broad" but they are good and interesting questions. For example, [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105834/why-does-owasp-recommend-security-questions). I see 2 questions in this one. #1. Is using security questions a good idea? #2. Why is OWASP recommending all those things to reset a password? Both of these questions are interesting to answer and might end up in lengthy answer by themselves.

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend against it. We have formatting tools for a reason. Often times it's better to find an article(or write one), post a link to it, and give bullet points with enough information that they could read the bullet points and get the general idea. There have been some lengthy answers before, but if split up properly, correctly, and in a good manner a long question is as easy to navigate as **CTRL+F**.

1. We have lists
2. They can be ordered

   - or unordered
   - these are helpful

---

Horizontal rules are helpful as well in breaking up content

### Headers are awesome

> Blockquotes can be a great thing to help highlights something important(like the question in question or some information that's really important)

Using these formatting tools and bold and italic I don't see why a long answer should be more than one answer. Just make sure to keep it clean and concise.

Answer (score 9):

I'd definitely recommend Robert's answer in many cases, however if the separate parts of a question are very disparate, don't make separate answers - split them off into separate questions.

In your example given, it makes perfect sense to create 2 questions and not just that single broad one.

Then you can answer each question precisely.

Comment: What is the procedure for turning *someone else's* question into 2 questions?

Comment: Generally we'd comment to recommend the OP does it. If they don't, just cut'n'paste one section into a new question and add a cross reference into each post.